# Nginx 502 bad gateway while hosting strapi application on ubuntu(18.04.1) instance

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy, strapi

NGINX 502 Bad Gateway

I am trying to host my strapi application on aws lightsail on Ubuntu 18.04 and adding nginx for the reverse proxy the strapi application server is all default on localhost.

Previously without nginx it showed

```
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/init' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:".
```

Hence i sorted out that nginx reverse proxy is needed. And below is my  Nginx location directives and env file of the strapi application.

```
.......................... /etc/nginx/sitesavailable/default .......................

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 
server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_buffers 8 16k;
                proxy_buffer_size 32k;
        }
}


................................. /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.................................................

........................... On Strapi..........................................
-----------------------------------server.js---------------------------------
 
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
 host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
 port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
 app: {
 keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
});


---------------------------------------database.js---------------------------------
 
const path = require("path");

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
 connection: {
 client: "postgres",
 connection: {
 host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
 port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
 database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "****"),
 user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "****"),
 password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "****"),
 ssl: {
 rejectUnauthorized: env.bool("DATABASE_SSL_SELF", false),
      },
    },
 debug: false,
  },
});

--------------------------------------.env---------------------------------
 
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
```

Comment: searching the internet, looks like it is not a nginx problem...

Comment: A.Herlas I couldn't figure out how did the issue occurred. Backend is working fine on the similar setup on the same server.